# Fazendo MySQL UPDATE em banco DB de acordo com MySQL SELECT em banco DB2

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, select

Preciso fazer `update` em um campo `office` de uma tabela `investidor` do banco de dados `b2c` no meu site.
Contudo, esse `update` dependerá de uma consulta `select` que é feita em outro banco de dados de outro site (ambos os sites pertencem à mesma empresa). Os dois bancos são em MySQL.

Abaixo o código que eu implementei:

```
    $emailInv = $this->email;
    $sqlNuevo = "SELECT DISTINCT uh.TIPO_INVESTIDOR FROM ipi_tst.uh
                JOIN ipi_tst.investidor i ON i.ID = uh.ID_INVESTIDOR
                JOIN ipi_tst.usuario u ON u.ID = i.ID_USUARIO
                WHERE u.EMAIL = '$emailInv' AND u.ID <> 0 ORDER BY FIELD(TIPO_INVESTIDOR,'P','C','O','A')";
    $rNew = System::element('db2')->query($sqlNuevo);
    if ($rNew[0]['TIPO_INVESTIDOR'] == 'O'){
        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '1' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
    }
    else if ($rNew[0]['TIPO_INVESTIDOR'] == 'A'){
        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '2' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
    }
    else {
        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '0' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
    }
```

Por enquanto, ele só consegue fazer `update` colocando valores Zero. Há casos em que dentro dessa tabela `uh` não tenha valores P ou C (`office` = 0). Pode ser que eu tenha apenas O ou apenas A, e aí precisaria fazer `update` colocando 1 ou 2, respectivamente.

O que pode estar errado? Não tenho certeza se ele conseguiu fazer a conexão com meu banco db2 (do outro site). O arquivo config.INI teve a adição dos dados database_portal. Eis o código desse arquivo (omiti algumas informações aqui por segurança e coloquei abaixo entre << e >> ):

```
[application]
versao = 1.0
titulo = B2C
default_pagina = index
default_metodo = index
default_erro = erro
default_erro_403 = erro403
default_erro_404 = erro404
default_login = login
debug = 0
idioma = pt-BR
moeda = RS
identificador = ipi_

[mensagem]
fundo = #000000
cor = #ffffff
delay = 2000
posicao = bottom

[dir]
raiz[localhost] = http://localhost/
raiz[<<MEU IP DO SITE>>] = <<MEU IP DO SITE>>
raiz[<<MEU LINK DO SITE>>] = <<MEU LINK DO SITE>>

[database]
db_alias = db
db_type = mysql
db_name = b2c
db_hostname = localhost
db_username = <<LOGIN DO db>>
db_password = <<SENHA DO db>>
db_port = 3306

[database_portal]
db_alias = db2
db_type = mysql
db_name = ipi_tst
db_hostname = <<IP DO OUTRO SITE>>
db_username = ipi_tst
db_password = ipi_tst
db_port = 3306

[cookie]
duracao = 10800
caminho = /
dominio = 

[mail]
mailer_type = system
admin_email = admin@framework.com
admin_name = "Admin - Framework"
smtp_server = mail.framework.com 
smtp_port = 25;
x_mailer = "xxxxx"
smtp_server = "mail.framework.com"
smtp_port = 25
smtp_timeout = 30

[logging]
nivel_log = 200
handler_log = file
arquivo_log = erros.log

[document_root]
root = <<DIRETÓRIO RAIZ>>
rootDSV = <<OUTRO DIRETÓRIO>>

[version]
atual_version = 1.5
```

E tem também o `libBanco.php`, incluso dentro do diretório `trunk/libs/libBanco`. Nesse arquivo só inclui a função `switch` relacionada com o banco do outro site (db2 ou database_portal):

```
<?php
$dir = '../libs/libBanco'; 

require_once("$dir/banco.php");
require_once("$dir/modeloBanco.php");

switch(Config::retorna('database', 'db_type')) {
    case 'oracle':
        require_once('oracle.php');
        $db = new Oracle();            
        break;
    case 'mysql':
        require_once('mysql.php');
        $db = new Mysql();            
        break;            
    default:
        $db = null;
        break;
}

switch(Config::retorna('database_portal', 'db_type')) {
    case 'oracle':
        require_once('oracle.php');
        $db2 = new Oracle();
        break;
    case 'mysql':
        require_once('mysql.php');
        $db2 = new Mysql();
        break;
    default:
        $db2 = null;
        break;
}

System::define(Config::retorna('database', 'db_alias'), $db);
System::define(Config::retorna('database_portal', 'db_alias'), $db2);
?>
```

Não sei se faltou alguma configuração nesse caso também. O que pode ser? Espero que seja só algum erro no sqlNuevo do código que implementei inicialmente.